# WebSphere v7 for custom password encryption says to implement a decrypt method, but what if I'm encrypting using SHA-256?

Tags: java, security, encryption

I followed the steps here:

[Enabling a plugpoint for custom password encryption](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/tsec_plugpoint_custpass_encrypt.html)

In particular, implementing the interface given here:

[Plug point for custom password encryption](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/csec_plugpoint_custpass_encrypt.html)

However, I'm using SHA-256 encryption, i.e.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
```

But, how can I implement a decrypt method for SHA-256? I thought the whole idea was that SHA-256 can't be decrypted?

Comment: And what if if turns out that hashing is not encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHA-256 does not decrypt. Use AES.